# IE8 compatibilty mode: scrollbar hides content

Tags: overflow, ie8-compatibility-mode

When I try the following code in IE8 compatibility mode, the scroll bar hides the content.

```
<style>
.myclass {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 400px;
}
</style>
<div class="myclass">
ReallyLongTextHere123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
</div>
```

This only happens when there is a long string with no spaces. Other browsers and newer versions of IE8 display this correctly.

Is there a way to fix this issue without affecting the way it looks on other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.myclass {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 400px;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Modify your css like this.